# How Can I Write If Statement In Effective Way Or In Single Line

Tags: vb.net

When I click edit button I want all my fields highlighted in textboxes thats why I had write this `if` statement from this problem has been solved. But can we write this in single line?

```
   If sCon.sqlReader.HasRows Then
        sCon.sqlReader.Read()
        txtStreetName.Text = sCon.sqlReader("StreetName")           
        'txtTypeDesc.Text = sCon.sqlReader("catDesc")


            'If sCon.sqlReader("cityID").ToString() <> "" Then
            '    cboCity.SelectedValue = sCon.sqlReader("cityID")
            'End If
            'If sCon.sqlReader("StateID").ToString() <> "" Then
            '    cboState.SelectedValue = sCon.sqlReader("stateID")
            'End If
            'If sCon.sqlReader("countryID").ToString() <> "" Then
            '    cboCountry.SelectedValue = sCon.sqlReader("countryID")
            'End If
        End If
```

Comment: what is the issue with empty string assignment?

Comment: Here's the documentation to the IIF operator. Is that what you're looking at ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @GameAlchemist - The use of `IIF` in VB.NET is deprecated as it is not type safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IsDBNull(sCon.sqlReader("cityID")) Then
                cboCity.SelectedIndex = -1
            Else
                cboCity.SelectedValue = sCon.sqlReader("cityID")
            End If

or

IIF(IsDBNull(sCon.sqlReader("cityID")),"",sCon.sqlReader("cityID"))

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of these:

*Option 1:*

```
Dim foo as String = iif(bar = buz, cat, dog)
```

*Option 2:*

```
Dim foo As Integer? = If( someTrueExpression, Nothing, 2)
```

*Option 3:*

```
Dim foo as String = If(bar = buz, cat, dog)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The use of `IIF` in VB.NET is deprecated as it is not type safe